# Right-tailed Inverse of the Student's t-distribution

Tags: excel, statistics

Excel provides a function for determining the left-tailed inverse of the Student's t-distribution.

```
T.INV(probability,deg_freedom)
```

If I needed the right-tailed inverse, can someone confirm if these are valid statistical operations (both lead to the same answer)

```
T.INV(1-probability,deg_freedom)
ABS(T.INV(probability,deg_freedom))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first formula is valid.   The second is not.  Consider asking for the right-tailed inverse of p = .75.  That should be a negative number, which the second formula can't be because of the ABS.